# ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem delegate never gets called

Tags: multithreading, xamarin.ios, threadpool

I am using MonoTouch 4.03. I have some code like this:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem (delegate
{
     Debug.WriteLine("Making connect request");
     client.Connect();
});
```

About one in 10 times it doesn't get fired. I'm only making very light use of ThreadPool.

NOTE (added 19th July): Currently I have turned LLVM optimisation off and that appears to have cured it.

Comment: it really depends on what client.Connect() does.

Comment: Thanks @miguel.de.icaza, however in these failure cases it doesn't make it to the Debug statement. Connect() connects to a remote socket. Nine out of ten times it works perfectly and the rest of the ThreadPool calls work fine too.

Comment: Does it help if you remove the Debug line?

Comment: Nope - it was doing it before that. I guess I could try it without an anonymous delegate. My money is on it not making any difference.

Comment: I did something similar (to set a button text after a delay) and it works every time. Can you make a more complete sample ? (here or by filling a bug report on bugzilla.xamarin.com).

Comment: I definitely will post a bug report when I can produce a complete sample - trouble is, if I unwrap it into a small sample app, it doesn't happen. Currently I have turned LLVM optimisation off and that appears to have cured it.

Comment: Also just to add to this - I'm using ThreadPool absolutely all over the place in this app and it's all fine aside from this first connect request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in MonoTouch 4.06 (or possibly the version before - in any case, it's fixed). I suspect the LLVM optimiser. The MonoTouch release notes show a number of bug fixes in that area.